# How can I ensure exception type safety?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, sqlexception, servicemodelex

I am using some code adapted from Lowy's ServiceModelEx to package an exception inside a `FaultException`, send it across the wire, and then unpack it on the client as a .NET `Exception`. My server can throw exceptions of theoretically any kind, but let's use a `SqlException` as an example.

Lowy uses reflection to unpack, so the code needs to examine the type of the exception to determine whether it can construct a valid object:

```
    static Exception ExtractException(ExceptionDetail detail)
    {
        Exception innerException = null;
        if (detail.InnerException != null)
        {
            innerException = ExtractException(detail.InnerException);
        }
        Type type = Type.GetType(detail.Type);
        Debug.Assert(type != null, "Make sure this assembly contains the definition of the custom exception");
        Debug.Assert(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Exception)));

        //...
    }
```

Two questions

1. With SqlExceptions, that first Debug.Assert fails. Trying to get them to resolve on the client, I have set a reference to `System.Data`, but no luck. I'm assuming this is because, without any actual `System.Data` invocation in that client, the compiler removes the reference? What can I do, in the short term, to get my client to resolve that `.GetType` call?
2. What is the correct way to "rethrow" the `LambdaException` as a base `ExceptionDetail` without losing granularity of detail (e.g. `StackTrace`) and without needing any assembly reference on the client side? Is this even possible?

**EDIT**: this is the source that wraps the `ExceptionDetail` as a `FaultException` on the server. Again, this is mostly from Lowy's ServiceModelEx:

```
    public static void PromoteException(Type serviceType, Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        //Is error in the form of FaultException<T> ? 
        if (error.GetType().IsGenericType && error is FaultException)
        {
            Debug.Assert(error.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FaultException<>));
            return;
        }

        ExceptionDetail exdetail = new ExceptionDetail(error);
        FaultException<ExceptionDetail> faultException = new FaultException<ExceptionDetail>(exdetail);

        MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, faultException.Action);

        //...
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to reference `System.Data`. Using `Type.GetType(detail.Type, true)` should produce a more informative error.

Comment: What exception was thrown by `Type.GetType`? (I'm trying to understand why the assert fails in question 1. I'll let someone else address question 2.)

Comment: @MichaelLiu Apologies, that was completely false--a competing initiative here had swapped out that exception type on me. Error returned is "Could not load type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' from assembly '...'" Have removed my other misleading comments.

Comment: What assembly is it trying to load SqlException from? What is the entire content of `detail.Type`?

Comment: @MichaelLiu My assembly, that's the fully typed name represented by ... detail.Type is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`, as expected

Comment: You didn't post the code that initializes `detail.Type`, but it needs to include the assembly info as well: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...".

Comment: @MichaelLiu Added source. Not sure why that assembly info is not included.

Comment: How does the `ExceptionDetail` constructor initialize the `Type` property?

Comment: @MichaelLiu metadata says it is "the type string for the exception passed to the constructor". Read-only.

Comment: It looks like `ExceptionDetail` doesn't preserve the assembly information in the type string. So I don't think this approach will work for CLR exceptions, only for exceptions defined in your own assembly.

Comment: @MichaelLiu I follow your reasoning but 1) the type fails if I revert to using Lowy's original `Exception` object, too, so it's not an `ExceptionDetail` problem, it seems, but a wire problem and 2) if I catch the SqlException and throw an `ApplicationException` instead it works as expected, so it isn't only for assembly-defined exceptions.

Comment: It works for `Exception` and `ApplicationException` because `Type.GetType` looks in both the currently executing assembly and in mscorlib.dll (where `Exception` and `ApplicationException` are declared) if no assembly is specified in the type string. It doesn't work for types declared in any other assembly.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Right, I see that. That sounds like at least part of the answer then: make sure exceptions coming through the wire are either of executing assembly- or mscorlib-declared types. So it's down to Q2 now, and whether just, say, catching the `SqlException` and throwing a more generic type is a wise practice or not.